# Custom Cell is never nil (NOT using storyboard)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

at the Moment i have the following classes:

[image]

My Problem is that my Custom Cell Class "GTNewsCustomCell" is never called, i set some breakpoints in the .m file but nothing happend, than i realized that in my "cellForRowAtIndexPath" the cell is never nil!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"NewsCell";


GTNewsCustomCell *newsCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

if(newsCell == nil){

newsCell = [[GTNewsCustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

}

newsCell.titleLabel.text = [[self.newsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"title"];
NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:[[self.newsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"previewMessage"]];

newsCell.messageTextView.attributedText = attString;

return newsCell;
```

}

And here is a little part of my Code from my GTNewsCustomCell.m:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code

    self.messageTextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.messageTextView.backgroundColor = GTDefaultTextBackgroundColor;
    self.messageTextView.editable = NO;
    self.messageTextView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    self.messageTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    NSString *htmlTag = @"<b></b>";
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",htmlTag,self.messageTextView.attributedText];

    NSData *data = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    CGFloat fontSizeMultiplier = 1.1;
    CGFloat const DTCoreTextDefaultFontSize = 12.0;
    NSString * fontName = @"Helvetica";
    DTCSSStylesheet* css;


    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")){

        css = [[DTCSSStylesheet alloc] initWithStyleBlock:@"ul li{padding-left: -10px;}"];


        NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:fontSizeMultiplier], NSTextSizeMultiplierDocumentOption,
                                        fontName, DTDefaultFontFamily,
                                        @"purple", DTDefaultLinkColor,
                                        @"red", DTDefaultLinkHighlightColor,
                                        css,DTDefaultStyleSheet,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],DTUseiOS6Attributes,
                                        nil];

.
.
.
.
```

Here are some screenshots from my xib Files for more information:

My GTNewsTableViewController:

[image]

GTNewsCustomCell (FilesOwner):
[image]

GTNewsCustomCell (View):

[image]

GTNewsCustomCell:

[image]

Comment: This might happen if you register your cell in your table view like this `[_tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CellXib" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];`. If you're doing it, try putting all your styling in -awakeFromNib method of the table cell

Comment: Yes i do  UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"GTNewsCustomCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1]; I will test it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, since you're doing the registration of cells via tableView's method `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`. The `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` won't ever get called. If you'd like to do the styling, use -awakeFromNib method of your `UITableViewCell` subclass.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
  [super awakeFromNib];
  self.messageTextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  self.messageTextView.backgroundColor = GTDefaultTextBackgroundColor;
  self.messageTextView.editable = NO;
  self.messageTextView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: Now my Custom Cell get called, but my cell looks not what i expected, is there any chance to use the initWithStyle method?

Comment: Yes, do not use this: `UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"GTNewsCustomCell" bundle:nil]; [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];`

Answer (score 2):

with GTNewsCustomCell (FilesOwner), you will not be able to reuse this cell if needed. you should make it NSObject(FileOwner). and load this cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

by this way , you will get the same style of of your custom cell.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier= @"CustomCell";
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell ==  nil) {
    NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell"
                                                      owner:self//transfer ownership to self
                                                    options:nil];
    cell = [nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: So you mean i should only delete the "GTNewsTableViewController" from my Custom Cell and set the default value (NSObject)?

Comment: yes, only if you want to reuse this cell in more view controllers. in this case you dont need to do this even. in cellForRowAtIndexPath  you are loading your cell directly from nib file.

Comment: kk Thanks for the tip :)